# Parsing an inconsistent log file

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I have a log file that I want to parse and load into a database. I'm struggling with the best way to go about parsing it.

The log file is in the format *Category: Information*

```
Case Number: CASE01  
User ID: JOSM  
Software: Microsoft Word  
Date Started: 21-01-2010  
Date Ended: 22-01-2010
```

Thing is, there's other bits and pieces thrown into the log file that mean the information isn't always present on the same line. I also only want the information, not the category.

So far, I've tried stick it all into an array separated by \r\n, but I have to know the index of the information I want in order to consistently retrieve it, and that changes. I've also tried feeding it through StreamReader and saying

```
if (line.Contains("Case Number"))
{
    tbReport.AppendText("Case Number: " + line.Remove(0, 13) + "\r\n");
}
```

Which gets me the information I want, but makes it very hard to do anything with.

I feel I'm better off going down the array path, but I could do with some guidance on how to search the array for the the category, and then parse the information.

Once I can parse it accurately, adding it into a database should be fairly straight forward. As it's my first time attempting this, I'd be interested in any tips or guidance as to the best way to go about this though.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of "other bits and pieces"?  Without knowing exactly what that looks like, we can't write you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a collection with all key/value pairs.

```
List<KeyValuePair> items = new List<KeyValuePair>();

var line = reader.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    int pos = line.IndexOf(':');
    items.Add(new KeyValuePair(line.Substring(0, pos), line.Substring(pos+1));

    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

If you have a log class which contains all possible names as properties, you can use reflection instead:

```
class LogEntry
{
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Software{ get; set; }
    public string DateStarted { get; set; }
    public string DateEnded { get; set; }
}

List<LogEntry> items = new List<LogEntry>();

var line = reader.ReadLine();
var currentEntry = new LogEntry();
while (line != null)
{
    if (line == "") //empty line = new log entry. Change to your delimiter.
    {
         items.Add(currentEntry);
         currentEntry = new LogEntry();
    }

    int pos = line.IndexOf(':');
    var name = line.Substring(0, pos).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    var value = line.Substring(pos+1);

    var pi = entry.GetType().GetProperty(name);
    pi.SetValue(entry, value, null);


    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Note that I've not tested the code (just written it directly in here). You have to add error checking and such. The last alternative is not very performant as it is, but should do OK.

Comment: That gave me exactly what I needed and introduced me to KeyValuePairs. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good case candidate for RegExp :

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

They're not too easy to learn but once you get the basic understanding, they can't be beaten for that kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a simple answer, but have you maybe though about using a regular expression for parsing the information out?

Regular expressions is kinda hardcore stuff, but they can parsed advanced files quite easily.

So in what I can see, then its like:

> If a line starts with A-Z, then (a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or space) from zero to many times, then followed by a : then a space, and then the value.

So if you make a regular expression for that (If you wait awhile I will try to make one for you), then you could test each line with that. If it matches, then we can also use regular expressions to take the last part out, and the "key". If it don't matches, then we just append it to the last key.

Beware that its not totally fool-proof, as a new line could just start this way, but its kinda the best thing we can do, i think.

**As promised here is a starting point for your regular expression:**

`^(?'key'[A-Z][a-z,A-Z,0-9,\s]+):\s(?'value'.+)`

So to try and tell what it does, we need to go though each part:

- **^** ensures that a match starts on the beginning of a line
- **(?'key'** is a syntax to begin a "capture" group. The regular expression will then give us access to easily take the "key" part of the regular expression out.
- We that with a **[A-Z]** - that is a group that will match any big letter. But only one
- **[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\s]+** - is like the previous group, but just for all big, or small letters, numbers and space (\s), the plus outside the group tells that it can match more than one.
- Then we just end the group, and puts in out **:* and then a space.
- We then begin a new group the **value** group, just like the key group.
- Then we just write **.** (that means everything), and then just a **+** after that to make it catch more than one

I actually think that you can just take the whole string, and just match a:

RegEx.Matches (or something like that), and loop over them.

Then just take match.Groups["key"] and match.Groups["value"] and put into your array. (Sorry i dont have a Visual Studio handy to test it out)

Comment: I'm actually fairly comfortable with regex as a concept (I use it a lot with TextPad) but thank you very much for the offer to start one. So the logic would be to have a regex for each line of the log file I want to read, and then test each line of the array against each line of the log file? Or test the whole text file against each regex?

Comment: Hi David,

I've posted a regular expression that seams to work.